# How to make state map with clickable districts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, wordpress, html

I want to make a state map (eg. http://futurewiz.in/map/interactive-map-of-india.html ) having clickable districts and redirecting to another page in word-press site. Can anyone guide about any plugin or tell me how to do that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is off topic because it is a request for a tutorial. Please see [ask] for more information regarding what questions are on topic for Stack Overflow. With that being said, what you're looking for is called an Image Map. See this for an example: https://html.com/images/how-to-make-an-image-map/

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the way to do is to draw a regions for district and add click event for each regions.

Following is the example, by which you can draw a region:

```
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),         {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: 51.204458, lng: 4.389025},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
  var coord_antzuid = [
      {lat: 51.208340, lng: 4.383368},
      {lat: 51.204458, lng: 4.389025},
      {lat: 51.208824, lng: 4.402478},
      {lat:51.211654, lng:4.400858},
      {lat: 51.212420, lng: 4.393971},
      {lat: 51.213737, lng:4.390288}
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var region = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coord_antzuid,
    strokeColor: '#36688F',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#36688F',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  region.setMap(map);

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  region.addListener('click', showArrays);

  google.maps.event.addListener(region,"mouseover",function(){
   this.setOptions({fillColor: "#CC6633", strokeColor: "#CC6633"});
  }); 

  google.maps.event.addListener(region,"mouseout",function(){
    this.setOptions({fillColor: "#36688F", strokeColor: "#36688F"});
  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
}

/** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
function showArrays(event) {
  // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
  // MVCArray of LatLngs.
  var vertices = this.getPath();

  var contentString = '<h3>Antwerpen Zuid</h3>' +
      '<strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong><br>John Smith <br>Kerkstraat 01 <br>2000 <br>Antwerp <br>00 000 00 00 <br> john@smith.me'

  // Replace the info windows content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

To achieve your requirement, what you need to do is, you need to get co-ordinates of all the district, and then draw a region in loop for all the district.

For each region, you need to bind click event, and on click of that you need to call a function (given in example how to bind click event).
And in that function, you have to perform your action what you want to do.

Please let me know if you need more help regarding this.

Thanks!